# view name associated with an action method may be different

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was reading a book which says:

**"If the view name is not specified in the ViewResult object, then the value of the action variable from the routing data will be used. For most controllers, this means that the name of the method will be used so that the default view file associated with the Index method is Index.cshtml. However, if you have used the Route attribute, then the view name associated with an action method may be different."**

but I did some tests like:

```
[Route("[controller]/MyAction")]
public ViewResult Index()
{
   string s = RouteData.Values["action"];
   return View();
}
```

so string s is "Index", which is the same as action method name, so how  view name associated with an action method may be different?

Answer (score 0):

For ViewName, it is controlled by `ActionName`.

As [Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing)

> The route templates above don't define route parameters for action,
>   area, and controller. In fact, these route parameters are not allowed
>   in attribute routes. Since the route template is already associated
>   with an action, it wouldn't make sense to parse the action name from
>   the URL.

Route Attribute would not affect the action name, and then it would not affect the view selection.

If you want to change the viewname by action name, you could try `ActionName` like

```
[ActionName("TestViewAction")]
public IActionResult TestView()
{
    string view = RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    return View();
}
```